# How do I apply conditional formatting using datatables.js?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a html table that uses datatables.js and have not been able to find a clear example of how to apply conditional formatting.

How could I change the text color of a cell in column 4 when its value == 0 and the value in column 5 is !=0

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GeneratedData").dataTable({
          "sDom": 'T<"clear">lrtip',
          "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "http://localhost:5637/Content/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
          },
           "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });
      })
</script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**. The original answer were targeting dataTables 1.9.x. It still works, and works with dataTables 1.10.x as well (so far) but here is a pure dataTables 1.10.x version :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
    if (data[3]=='0' && data[4]!='0') {
      $(row).find('td:eq(3)').addClass('color')
    }   
  }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2chjxduy/**

---

You should use the [`fnRowCallback`](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) event for this. From the docs :

> This function allows you to 'post process' each row after it have been
>   generated for each table draw, but before it is rendered on screen.
>   This function might be used for setting the row class name etc.

So in your case, do this :

```js
$("#GeneratedData").dataTable({
   //your settings as above here
   fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
       if ($(nRow).find('td:eq(3)').text()=='0' &&
           $(nRow).find('td:eq(4)').text()!='0') {
              $(nRow).find('td:eq(3)').addClass('color');
           }   
    }
});
```

`color` is a predefined CSS class. See it in action in this jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/GfNeA/

Comment: When setting by options in the current version, we have also `createdRow`, which *can often be more efficient*).
Links for both options:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow
https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback