# dc.js dataTable Conditional formatting using jquery dataTable

Tags: datatables, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dashboard which is built using dc.js and i'm using the chart types dc.rowChart and dc.dataTables.
**Working Scenario with without conditional formatting:** 

dc.rowChart - displays Top 50 Customers 
dc.dataTable - displays all the fields required and filters the data based on the rowChart. 
**Working Scenario with conditional Formatting (on datatable rows)** 
In my HTML, i'm calling the jquery plugin for DataTable (for conditioanl formatting) and here is the code below:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Table").DataTable( {
    /*
        fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
      if ($(nRow).find('td:eq(7)').text()<'0') {
              $(nRow).find('td:eq(7)').addClass('color');
          }   
    }

    */                
                 columns : [
                 { title : "Customer Name" },

                 { title : "YoY Rank Change" ,

                 render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                if (data > '0') {
                    return '<p class="positive">'+data+'</p>';
                } else {
                    return '<p class="negative">'+data+'</p>';
                } } },

                 { title : "Jan'19 Qty" },
                 { title : "Dec'18 Qty" },
                 { title : "Nov'18 Qty" },
                 { title : "Oct'18 Qty" },
                 { title : "Sep'18 Qty" },
                 { title : "Aug'18 Qty" }
                ]   

       } );
    } );

    $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,

    } );
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
    .negative {
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,1.00);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    }
   .positive {
    background-color:rgba(50,205,50,1.00);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

**ISSUE HERE**
When i render the page first time, everything with the datatable with conditional formatting works fine
But when i click on Row Chart to filter datatable based on Customer's, Conditional formatting is gone... 
Any help is much appreciated to fix this. 
 
I have tried almost all the stack answers but i'm not able to achieve it. 
**references used below:**
1. [How to color code rows in a table dc.datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156839/how-to-color-code-rows-in-a-table-dc-datatable/29172240#29172240)
2. [How do I apply conditional formatting using datatables.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731030/how-do-i-apply-conditional-formatting-using-datatables-js) 
3. [Color code a data table in dc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807699/color-code-a-data-table-in-dc-js?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [How to color code rows in a table dc.datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156839/how-to-color-code-rows-in-a-table-dc-datatable) ( This is opted out as i dont want to color code entire row)

@Gordon my survivor at all times.. Looking for your inputs please!!

Comment: Please consider using [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview) or [dc.datatables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js) instead of creating a `dc.dataTable` and then transforming it with `$.DataTable` - these libraries deal with redraw better. As you point out, `$.DataTable` is a one-way transformation and then nothing gets updated after that (without more work, which is what these libraries are about).

Comment: @Gordon, i'm not able to fix it using dc-tableview nor using dc.datatables.js. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ssbs/tf5ce7j0/51/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are still on dc.js 2.0, so I didn't attempt to port this to [dc.datatables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js) or [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview). I still think that would be more maintainable.

As I noted in the comments, `$.DataTable` is a one-way transformation: once you have done this, there is no way to update the table, because `dc.dataTable` doesn't recognize the DOM structure anymore, and DataTable [doesn't have a way to reinitialize](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3).

There might be some smart way to get DataTables to update the data (and this is what the libraries do). It's also madly inefficient to first build a table and then construct a DataTable using the DOM as a data source.

But whatever, let's just get this working by building the DataTable from scratch every time the `dc.dataTable` is drawn.

The way to do this is to listen for the table's `pretransition` event, remember if we've already initialized DataTable, and if we have, destroy the old instance:

```
var dt = null;
table.on('pretransition', function() {
    if(dt)
        dt.destroy();
    dt = $("#dc-data-grid").DataTable( {
        // as before
    } );
});
```

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0mkrghf2/44/). I had to fix a few other things, but I won't go into the details.

Comment: Its really not enough if i just say "THANK YOU".. It worked like a "Charm", I owe you a lunch / Dinner.. Let me know if you are here anytime to Atlanta :)

Comment: I used to be a Tableau developer and i did some bits and pieces of poc's using dc.js.. You know what?? Almost 15 dashboards built using dc.js and users loved it. All credit to the community and contributors :) Long Live..

Comment: That is so nice to hear. Thank you!