# After a table is initialized, the datatable column header disappears in Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome, datatables, dc.js

I have a DataTable which is generated upon a page load. The column header disappears / not initialized once it is loaded first time. Once i refresh the page again the column header gets loaded. 
 Note: This happens only in Chrome and not in firefox. 
 
 I have tagged dc.js because i render the dashboard with other charts using dc. 
 I had conditional formatting rendering issue earlier which gordon helped me fixing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146786/dc-js-datatable-conditional-formatting-using-jquery-datatable)

Comment: do you have any js error in the console? might be that something is breaking preventing the code that displays headers to run

Comment: @Xavier, i don't get any js error in the console.

Comment: Do you mean whole page refresh or dc.js charts redraw? If it's refresh, I don't know but it sounds like some sort of race condition. If it's dc.js redraw, then I'd suggest looking at how [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview) and [dc.datatables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js) handle render and redraw... or just use dc-tableview since it is compatible with dc.js 2.0.