# DataTables jquery color different cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Trying to css different cells in rows. But css is not works. Text by index row promts correct but i cant do something with data.

```
$('#results').DataTable( {
        "initComplete": function() {
            $rows    = $('#results').DataTable().rows().count();
            $columns = $('#results').DataTable().columns().count();
            
            for (var i = 1; i < $columns; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j < $rows; j++) {
                    if($('#results').DataTable().data()[j][i] != $('#results').DataTable().data()[j-1][i])
                    {
                        console.log($('#results').DataTable().data("test")[j][i].css("color","red");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Example of expentations:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at questions such as [How do I apply conditional formatting using datatables.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19731030/12567365) - or various [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+conditional+formatting+site:stackoverflow.com)? Did any of those help?

Comment: @andrewJames yes, but they are using function rowCallback not InitComplete ( that starts after loading ), my code using api data(), also they modify rows instead of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant works.

I put new data in cell with colored span with data inside.
And it works.

```
$('#results').DataTable().cell({row:j, column:i}).data("<span style='color:red;'>"+$('#results').DataTable().cell({row:j, column:i}).data()+"</span>");
```